# MySQL & predefined tags: One table solution?

Tags: mysql, tags

I have an `items` table that I would like to add tags. Users will be able to add up to three of 15 PREDEFINED tags to each item.

Usually, you would go for a `tag` table but as I have only a few predefined tags that will never change I wonder whether there is a simpler method.

I am thinking of having a field `tags` where each bit represents one of the predefined tags. I would `OR` the selected tags and store an `int`.

Now my question: What would a query look like that tells me which tags (bits from the int) have been set for a large number of rows?

Comment: do you intend to store 15 characters each of which can have a value of 0 or 1 where 1 represents a tag having been selected? Other than knowing bit 3 has been set (for example) how would you enrich this with something user friendly?

Comment: It would look exactly the same as for method one, because there's nothing 'simpler' about this misguided idea, so you wouldn't do it.

Comment: P.Salmon: I intend to store ONE 16-bit integer where each bit represents a specific tag. If a tag is used, the corresponding bit is set. Easy, peasy.

Comment: Easy, peasy eh - is there a quesion then?(rhetorical question)

Comment: While it might be programmatically a bit simpler to set and unset the tags compared to, lets say, a comma separated list, you approach will face similar problems as every other kind of solution that isn't normalized (in your case, it is not in 1st normal form). Any question on stackoverflow where an answer or comment contains a version of "you didn't normalize your data" can give you an impression of the consequences of that decision.

Comment: I agree – partially. I would think that in this special case, where there is a limited, predefined set of tags, a simpler solution than building three tables (items, tags, items_tags) can be considered. I just can not get my head around how a query would look like that would present the tags of a group of items (to find out which tags are set at all to only show those for the user to choose from).

Comment: Basically: relational databases work best with normalized data (e.g. in bcnf). If you do not need anything else that the database has to offer (indexes, aggregation, constraints, ...), and if for your requirements your approach works (best or equally fine), and/or you really really need to save storage space, noone will/can force you not to do this. Some tasks that are more complicated with your approach though: counting how many tags are used/most popular; using indexes; checking which combination of tags are most commonly used; enforcing a 3 tag limit; adding tags (requirements may change).

Answer (score 0):

While I don't actually recommend using it, this is what the [`SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html) datatype was designed for.

It's stored in the column as an integer with each bit representing one of the tags. But when you fetch the value, it's returned as a comma-separated list of the tags, and you can assign values the same way. To tell if a specific tag is in a value, you use the `FIND_IN_SET()` function.

You can also access the numeric value of the column. This is useful if you want to mask some of the bits.

The documentation linked above provides more details, as well as some caveats.

While the storage space is quite efficient, most operations on set values can't make effective use of indexes. For instance, searching for all the rows with a specific tag will require a full scan.